# Поворот экрана при запуске приложения Android

Tags: java, android

Как сделать, чтобы при запуске приложения оно запускалось сразу в `landscape` моде, игнорируя текущую ориентацию телефона?

Я поставил в манифесте `android:screenOrientation="landscape"`. При запуске приложения, когда телефон в `landscape` моде, приложение запускается без проблем, но если телефон в вертикальной ориентации, то приложение вылетает.

Comment: С какой ошибкой вылетает? Покажите исключение

Comment: я только учусь и не знаю как использовать исключения, но при запуске приложения выдыается "В приложении ... произошла ошибка."

Answer (score 4):

Простите меня, я идиот. Прописав в манифесте android:screenOrientation="landscape" я неверно закрыл тег и поэтому вылетало.

Answer (score 2):

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity);
}
```